# How can i make stream for zip archiving for long files

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, zip, gzip

How can i make stream for zip archiving for long files?  i making server that will upload video for anything size (1>gb) and it will split that video into parts , and return users that parts in zip archive. Or is great npm for that solutions with examples?

I have been using ADM ZIP (npm module). That works great, until using big files. So i need solutions in streams. I have try something like this:

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var fs = require('fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz');

inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

But how i can add to this arhive more than one file, and how i can realize that with event ?

```
inp.on('data', function(data) { 
  // add data to zip and do other things like counthing percent processing
});
```